# How to reject update attribute if param is blank or empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hstore

I have form

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for User.new do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :email %>
   <%= text_field_tag "user[data[first_name]]" %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller#create**

```
@user = User.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:user][:email])

if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  ...
```

How to reject update user hstore `date` attribute if params(in that case `first_name`) is empty or blank?

Comment: Are you using any validations on the `User` model?

Comment: With a validation: `validates :first_name, presence: true` in the user model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you are taking a wrong strategy for the `create` action. Just do

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.save
```

If you want to ensure that `email` is *unique* across users, use a Rails' validation like so:

```
class User
  #...
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  #...
end
```

Your approach will modify an existing user with the same email during a create. Sounds wrong.

For more details, have a look at the `create` of a *scaffolded* controller.

Comment: I am saving all new fields in hstore data column. And I want to be able to override existing user.